# Melodic - HardwareInterface - Freezes when commanding non Zero cmd

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
the Problem I encounter is that my HardwareInterface Node/Program freezes when I order commands trough Teleop_Twist_Keyboard or else.  The Process jumps above 100% (of single core, enough resources left) and just freezes. If I dont order any command, the base controller outputs Zero, it works fine. Data from the encoders comes in, no problem. But when I command something (value doesnt matter) it just freezes. Is there some known behaviour in the ros_control controllers that might cause this or any other idea whats going wrong here?

HW Interface is based on [link text](https://github.com/cyborg-x1/ros_control_test) cyborg-x1

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338380/melodic---hardwareinterface---freezes-when-commanding-non-zero-cmd/) by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 574 on 2019-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved the Problem by brute force logging, it was my "ParityBit" generating loop. "^=" works well with zero, but not with Double into Int.

---

Originally posted by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) with karma: 574 on 2019-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0